# Can I override a theme function from a contributed module

Tags: theming

Per this question, [Can I modify guestbook.module safely?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36159/can-i-modify-guestbook-module-safely) I have overridden `theme_guestbook_entry()` from the guestbook.module file.  The problem is that my modifications are not taking effect. (Yes, I rebuilt the cache.)

I am following these instruction here, http://drupal.org/node/11811. I notice they don't mention contributed modules at all. Am I able to override these?

Answer (score 5):

The page you are referring is for Drupal 5.

In Drupal 6, you alter a theme function defined in a module by defining the theme function, as in the following code. (Replace mytheme with the short name of your theme.)

```
// Drupal 6
function mytheme_guestbook_entry($uid, $entry, $comment_entry = NULL, $zebra, $confirm_delete = FALSE) {
  // Your own code.
}
```

```
// Drupal 7
function mytheme_guestbook_entry($variables) {
  // … 
}
```

In Drupal 7, if you just want to alter the variables passed to the theme function, you need to implement the preprocess function for that theme function.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_guestbook_entry(&$variables) {
  // Alter the values passed to the function, such as $variables['uid'], $variables['entry'],
  // $variables['comment_entry'], $variables['zebra'], or $variables['confirm_delete'].
}
```

The code I shown works whatever a theme function is implemented in Drupal, or a third-party module.